# Return values that satisfy multiple conditions

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a query that returns all rows except for those that meet two conditions in the same row.

I have tried a few variations of the code below but have not had any luck.

```
Select *
from ad_data
where (app <> 'instagram' and vendor <> 'Doubleclick')
and event_date between '2018-7-06' and '2018-7-12'
```

Essentially I just want this query to return all rows in the table except for those where the app is instagram and the vendor is doubleclick.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the query shown based on the description. perhaps showing sample data and the expected output would help us understand better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean **OR**

```
Select *
    from ad_data
where (app <> 'instagram' OR vendor <> 'Doubleclick')
and event_date between '2018-7-06' and '2018-7-12'
```

Criteria 1: `(app <> 'instagram' OR vendor <> 'Doubleclick')`

All rows excluded having app = 'instagram' AND vendor = 'dbl...'

Because: !(A&&B) = (!A || !B) [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Or see it like this: You want to exclude when both criterias meet. Is the same as: You want to NOT exclude when one criteria does not meet.

---

Criteria 2: `event_date between '2018-7-06' and '2018-7-12'`

Answer (score 0):

Hoping, I understood your question correctly. Please check below query.

```
    Select *
    from ad_data
    where (coalesce(app,'x') <> 'instagram' and coalesce(vendor,'x') <> 'Doubleclick')
    and event_date between '2018-7-06' and '2018-7-12'
```